# Квадратные кнопки для тулбара

Tags: java, swing

Использую для реализации тулбара класс JToolBar. И добавляю туда кнопки JButton. Ширина кнопки берется минимальная. То есть если я добавляю кнопку с текстом "I" или "J" (или другим коротким текстом),

```
toolbar.add(new JButton("J"));
```

то получается кнопка с шириной в несколько (<10) пикселей. Хотелось бы чтобы такие кнопки становились квадратными, т.е. чтобы ширина была хотя бы равна длине. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так установите для кнопки размер. Например, вот такой код выдаёт то что нужно

[image]

```
package cg;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

/**
 * @author Sergey Mashkov
 */
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    public MainFrame() throws HeadlessException {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setTitle("My toolbar test");
        add(createToolbar(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        setSize(800, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private static JToolBar createToolbar() {
        return new MyToolbarBuilder()
                .add("Hello", createEmptyAction())
                .add("I", createEmptyAction())
                .add("My long long button", createEmptyAction())
                .get();
    }

    private static class MyToolbarBuilder {

        private final JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();

        private MyToolbarBuilder() {
            tb.setBorderPainted(true);
            tb.setFloatable(false);
        }

        public MyToolbarBuilder add(String text, Action action) {
            tb.add(createToolbarButton(text, action));
            return this;
        }

        public JToolBar get() {
            return tb;
        }
    }

    private static JButton createToolbarButton(String text, Action action) {
        JButton btn = new JButton(action);
        btn.setText(text);

        Dimension size = createSize(32, 32);
        btn.setSize(size);
        btn.setMinimumSize(size);
        btn.setMaximumSize(size);
        btn.setPreferredSize(size);

        return btn;
    }

    private static Dimension createSize(int w, int h) {
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }

    private static Action createEmptyAction() {
        return new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```